# SD card with ESP32 cam : Passing file to a function

Tags: arduino, arduino-ide, arduino-c++

In this code I need to pass file to the function and then read it inside the function.
The problem I can not read anything. it print "Opening file to read failed"

```
#include "SD_MMC.h"

void printpassf(File &f){
  
  File file2 = SD_MMC.open("/f.txt", FILE_READ);
  if (!file2) {
    Serial.println("Opening file to read failed");
    return;
  }
  Serial.println("File Content:");
  while (file2.available()) {
    Serial.write(file2.read());
  }
}
 
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);

  if (!SD_MMC.begin()) {
    Serial.println("Failed to mount card");
    return;
  }
 
  File file = SD_MMC.open("/test.txt", FILE_WRITE);
 
  if (!file) {
    Serial.println("Opening file to write failed");
    return;
  }
  if (file.print("Test file write")) {
    Serial.println("File write success");
  } else {
    Serial.println("File write failed");
  }
  file.close(); 
  printpassf(file);
} 
void loop() {}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this function you a re taking a file object by reference and calling it f.

```
void printpassf(File &f){
  
  File file2 = SD_MMC.open("/f.txt", FILE_READ);
  if (!file2) {
    Serial.println("Opening file to read failed");
    return;
  }
  Serial.println("File Content:");
  while (file2.available()) {
    Serial.write(file2.read());
  }
}
```

You seem to be trying to use f as a filename.  f is a by reference variable in this function, it won't substitute for a random f in a string.  But moreover, the file is already open before you pass it to this function.

Try this version of your function.

```
void printpassf(File &f){
  Serial.println("File Content:");
  while (f.available()) {
    Serial.write(f.read());
  }
}
```